# Integrate new menu for admin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, jhipster

I work on a project jhipster

I have had a blockage is part of angularjs, I would like to integrate a menu in the admin profile so
I modified scripts/app/admin.js but nothing happens.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('pmappApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('admin', {
        'abstract' : true,
        parent : 'site',
        views : {
            'gmenu@' : {
                templateUrl : 'scripts/app/admin/gmenu/gmenu.html',
                controller : 'GmenuController'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The state is declared abstract, so it cannot be reached itself. Do you have child state under this?

Comment: no child state under admin

Comment: Then removing abstract: true should be fine I guess

Comment: did console report any error? judging from the code you also have a site state and a gmenu state?

Comment: no errors , but  nothing is displayed

Comment: can't know anything more without more information =(

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11542730/8335007/8c28b0a0-1a8a-11e5-9d75-6d8fb3957fef.png

Comment: I'm quite confuse now. If you want to access this state as it is, then it should not have abstract and have a url. You mentioned you "modified" the script, can you show me what is the original state of the code?

Comment: I'm going to bed now so I'll probably be quite a while until I come back @@

Comment: ok the original state of the code                                                             'use strict';

angular.module('pmappApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
 $stateProvider.state('admin', {
  abstract : true,
  parent : 'site',
  
  
 });
});

Comment: I appeal to js  with :<div ui-view="gmenu"></div>

Comment: ok, this make sense. You'll need to make sure you've added <div ui-view="gmenu"></div> in the correct place. I assume you added it in a HTML file, and you'll need to find the state that uses the HTML file as a template.

Comment: then change the view key to 'gmenu@statename', replace statename with the name of the state that uses the template.

Comment: I tried everything without success

Comment: I think the page html does not make the right call ?                                                                                                                         <div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak=""></div>
 
 <div ui-view="gmenu" ></div>

Comment: Can you give an example on how you replace navbar in existing code?

Comment: my navbar code: http://www.mediafire.com/view/15cx9btq3ya1nan/navbar.png

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/pnn00uf962ppc2y/webapp.rar

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
$stateProvider.state('admin', {
    'abstract' : true,
    parent : 'site',
    views : {
        'gmenu@' : {
            templateUrl : 'scripts/app/admin/gmenu/gmenu.html',
            controller : 'GmenuController'
        }
    }
});
```

I can see the additional menu are properly inserted while accessing /audits

Comment: did the url change to /audits or it redirect you to somewhere else?